# Android> passing reference of an activity to a BroadCastReceiver subclass

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

Getting the following error message

*`The method findViewById is undefined for the type new PhoneStateListener()`*

So my question is what is the proper way of passing reference of an activity to a BroadCastReceiver subclass?

My BroadcastReceiver subclass is below

```
package com.example.android;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class ServiceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
        TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        telephony.listen(new PhoneStateListener(){
            @Override
            public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
                super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
                Log.d("foo","incomingNumber : "+incomingNumber);

                EditText incomingNum = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputText);

                incomingNum.setText(incomingNumber);

            }
        },PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating a separate `Class` for the `BroadcastReceiver` you can create an anonymous inner `Class` inside the `Activity`. Then you can reference the `Activity`'s `findViewById()` by doing `MyActivityName.this.findViewById()`

Comment: Thanks! would this be considered a 'best practice' or a kludge? Shouldn't BroadcastReceivers normally reside in their own distinct Class files?

Comment: I do not think it is a requirement to define it in its own class. You can also define an interface in your `BroadcastReceiver` and make the `Activity` implement it, but I do not think that is the best option since the you will loose the "looseness" the mechanism provides.